# Decompressing a Zip file from a string

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, zip, gzip, couchbase

I'm fetching an object from couchbase where one of the fields has a file. The file is zipped and then encoded in base64.

How would I be able to take this string and decompress it back to the original file?

Then, if I'm using ASP.MVC 4 - How would I send it back to the browser as a downloadable file?

The original file is being created on a Linux system and decoded on a Windows system (C#).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use [`Convert.FromBase64String`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.convert.frombase64string.aspx) to get the bytes, then decompress, and then use [`Controller.File`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.controller.file%28v=vs.108%29.aspx) to have the client download the file. To decompress, you need to open the zip file using some sort of ZIP library. .NET 4.5's built-in [`ZipArchive`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.compression.ziparchive.aspx) class should work. Or you could use another library, both [SharpZipLib](http://www.icsharpcode.net/opensource/sharpziplib/) and [DotNetZip](http://dotnetzip.codeplex.com/) support reading from streams.

```
public ActionResult MyAction()
{
    string base64String = // get from Linux system
    byte[] zipBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(base64String);
    using (var zipStream = new MemoryStream(zipBytes))
    using (var zipArchive = new ZipArchive(zipStream))
    {
        var entry = zipArchive.Entries.Single();
        string mimeType = MimeMapping.GetMimeMapping(entry.Name);
        using (var decompressedStream = entry.Open())
            return File(decompressedStream, mimeType);
    }
}
```

You'll also need the MIME type of the file, you can use [`MimeMapping.GetMimeMapping`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mimemapping.getmimemapping.aspx) to help you get that for most common types.

Comment: I realized that .NET 4.5 includes a `ZipArchive` class that will work. Updated my answer to use that. I haven't tried it, so you might need to rework how you finish out reading the entry into a `byte[]` or `Stream`.

Answer (score 0):

I've used [SharpZipLib](http://www.icsharpcode.net/opensource/sharpziplib/) successfully for this type of task in the past.

For an example that's very close to what you need to do have a look [here](https://github.com/icsharpcode/SharpZipLib/wiki/Zip-Samples#wiki-anchorUnpackFull).

Basically, the steps should be something like this:

- you get the compressed input as a string from the database
- create a MemoryStream and write the string to it
- seek back to the beginning of the memory stream
- use the MemoryStream as an input to the SharpZipLib `ZipFile` class
- follow the example provided above to unpack the contents of the ZipFile

---

**Update**

If the string contains only the zipped contents of the file (not a full Zip archive) then you can simply use the [GZipStream](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.compression.gzipstream.aspx) class in .NET to unzip the contents. You can find a sample [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/as1ff51s.aspx). But the initial steps are the same as above (get string from db, write to memory stream, feed memory stream as input to the GZipStream to decompress).

Comment: Thanks - but it seems pretty outdated and without any documentation :/

Comment: @JohnMighty - no, it's not outdated. It's pretty widely used and as far as samples, have a look at the link in my updated answer.